# What recommendations exist for structuring TypeScript code bases?

Tags: typescript

I have been working with C# for years and am mostly used to the single-file-per-type way of doing things. I am also fond of putting files into subfolders (corresponding to namespaces in C#).

But now I'm building a mobile web application using TypeScript, and find myself structuring my code in much the same way. However, this doesn't work too well:

- Every file produces a module wrapper, so if you have many files with the same module the output (when bundled) contains a lot of unnecessary code lines.
- Referencing types in other modules is.. not as nice as in C#, as you have to prefix type names with module name.

The first point should be fixable by writing a small tool to strip out unnecessary module wrappers from the bundled output. And I'm thinking that I need to avoid using sub-modules and just stick everything into a single module, regardless of file system location.

Is there a better way to go about structuring TypeScript code than what I am currently doing/planning or would something like the above be recommend practice? What alternatives exist that are worth considering for someone who likes the single-responsibility principle?

PS: I hope this falls within the guidelines of SO, despite possibly being a bit subjective and open-ended.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here are my recommendations.

### Web Site

If you are using TypeScript on a web site, use modules to enclose a complete and stand-alone chunk of functionality and keep it in one file (unless it becomes unmanageable). Be conservative about how much access "module a" has to the inside bits of "module b".

Bundle and minify all of the generated JavaScript into a single file.

Declare your modules with:

```
module MyModule {
    // ...
}
```

And make them available to other code files using a reference:

```
///<reference path="MyModule.ts" />
```

### Web App

For a web app, you need to decide how script-heavy things are going to be. If things are going to be lightweight, treat it like a web site. If you are going to have a lot of scripts then AMD is your friend.

With AMD, you can use a folder structure to organise your code. Your files are your modules, so instead of using the `module MyModule` declaration, you name your file `MyModule.ts`. You can then organise your code using the folder and file structure and import the modules as you need them:

```
import myModule = module("./Messaging/Async/MyModule");
```

So think of the `import` as your `using` statement - except you need to give it a name.

At runtime, you'll need something to take care of loading the modules for you. [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) is a popular choice for this.

You just add one script tag to your page, which loads RequiresJS and tells it the name of your top-level module:

```
<script data-main="/Messaging/Async/MyModule" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

### Server App

For a server app, you are almost certainly going to want to use CommonJS (which is supported by default by nodejs, for example).

It works largely like AMD (AMD is actually based on CommonJS) except the server will load the modules for you, so you don't need to include a module-loading script.

### Golden Bullet

This is all guidance really. You could use web-site style bundling for really quite large programs if you wanted to - given that the script will be downloaded once and cached you may decide that the up-front cost is worth the simplicity.

So use the guidance until you think it doesn't fit your specific program and want to do things differently. The guidance is based on the principle of...

1. reducing the number of http requests for a web site
2. increasing the readability and maintainability for web app / server app
3. loading only what is required for a web app / server app

Comment: You can still use the `module MyModule` declaration with AMD, though. Just export it.

Comment: Great advice, thanks! Can I use AMD/CommonJS in a mobile web application that will run on the client device and load all of its JS from that device? Or should I still choose RequireJS for such a scenario? That said, right now I'm bundling everything into a single output file and therefore am more concerned about the write/design-time experience than how stuff is going to work at runtime, although the two concerns are obviously intertwined.

Comment: I would probably opt to bundle it all into one file if it was going to be deployed on the mobile device. No point going to all the trouble of module loading in that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite subjective, but for what it's worth we are using modules more or less as namespaces and therefore grouping together related classes in a single file, except in our viewmodel where we more or less stick to one file = one class, as we would for C#.

One reason for this is that in client-side development, we find ourselves creating many more very small classes and interfaces (often with only two or three parameters each), usually grouped about the workings of a particular component or view, and collating these in a single file just seems to make more sense.

Comment: I've also started lumping some types together, in particular the type definitions (interfaces) that are related to the class in the file. Pragmatism wins, but so far I'm OK with single-class, single-file :)